# Mysql - Parameter in Truncate Partition

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have partition name coming in a parameter ( `@partition_name` ) in a mysql statement.

Next I need to run something like this :

```
Alter table table1 truncate partition @partition_name
```

But this gives me syntax error.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Some things cannot be substituted like that.  Create a Stored Procedure.  In it CONCAT to construct the ALTER statement, then prepare it and execute it.